# is it possible to detect when a line breaks in a contentEditable?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I'm working with a contentEditable and wondering if it's possible to track when a line breaks and wraps? I'm trying to execute function when the current line exceeds the width of the contentEditable and breaks into a new line.

Not much else I can add, it's a pretty basic concept although it may not be a simple solution or even possible.